# Not matching in perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I have a variable and I want it to print success if it doesn't contained specific thing. But its always printing success even if its there.

```
$mystring = " 1 2 3 4 5 TEST=/my/user/test this/is/test
              3 4 5 6 8 NEW=/my/new/offer this/is/offer
              3 4 5 2 2 FINAL=/final/test/offer /lets/see/this";

if (($mystring !~ m/1 2 3 4 5 TEST=\/my\/user\/test this\/is\/test/i) or 
   ($mystring !~ m/3 4 5 2 2 FINAL=\/final\/test\/offer \/lets\/see\/this/i))
    {
      print "success";
}
```

Its printing success even if the mysstring contains the string. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think that `or` should be an `and`. Otherwise you are only *not* printing `success` when both patterns are present in the same string.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is missing a `;` at the end of the `$mystring` declaration.  And the second regular expression is unterminated, missing `/i` at the end.

With those changes your script works fine.  It prints "success" if one of the regexes does not match.  In your example script, both regexes match, and it does not print "success".

If you mean to print "success" if either regex matches, use `=~` instead of `!~`.

Comment: I have corrected both the things and still issue. Yes I want if either doesn't matches.